# Integral of a loop that doesn't encircle a current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In Griffith's Electrodynamics, if we calculate $\oint \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$, where the loop doesn't enclose the wire at all, then $\int d\phi=0$. I thought that $\int d\phi=\phi_2-\phi_1$ but why does it equal to zero?
[image: corresponding image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of integration runs over the whole loop so the integral is:
$$\int_{over loop} d\phi=\int_{I}d\phi+\int_{II}d\phi$$
where $\int_{I}d\phi$ =$\phi_2-\phi_1$ since it  going ccw from  lower tanget to upper tangent

and $\int_{I}d\phi$ =$\phi_1-\phi_2$ since it  going ccw from  upper tanget to lower tangent

therefore$$\int_{over loop} d\phi=\phi_2-\phi_1 +\phi_1-\phi_2 =0$$